# Geometric brainteaser

Tags: geometry

I am still studying for my exam and now I am thinking about this brain teaser. So I would really appreciate some help from you. I did found out already, that $x$ must be $46^\circ$, because of the radius, the $\Delta ABD$ is isosceles. Does anyone have an idea how to get the size of $\delta$ ?

My sheet says at the end $\delta$ should be $68^\circ$. But I don't know the way to prove it.

[image: brainteaser]

Comment: Do we know that arc DB is tangent to line DC?

Comment: no actually, I just added the line into the picture myself

Comment: yes thats true about the small and big circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important  to recognise is that there are two circles, one with center $A$ going through $E$ (call it $C1$, and one with center $E$ going through $C$, call it $C2$. $E$ is one time the center and the other time on the circumference.

$88$ is the angle at the center of $C1$ over the chord $DB$. $DEB$ is over the same chord $DB$ from the circumference of $C1$, but from the opposite side so you know how big it is.

$DEB$ is also the angle from the center of the circle $C2$ over that chord, and $\delta$ is an angle over that chord from the circumference of $C2$ from same side. So how big is that?

Comment: so DEB is 176 degrees?

Comment: I dont understand the last part onwards from "Deb is also the angle from the center of another...) would you mind to explain for me more??

Comment: Not quite. If you have angles over a chord from the same side, than the one at the center is twice as big as the one on the circumference. If you have two angles from the circumference then they are equal if they are on the same side and supplemental if they are on opposite sides.

Comment: but then it would be double of 88 first, which is 176 and then half again would be 88. but the answer is supposed to be 68. so it cant be true..

Comment: if i understood what you meant..

Comment: I hope I cleared it up a bit. If not: DEB is 180 minus the angle that is half of $88$ (that's what's meat with supplemental.)

Comment: ahhh now I got it. thank you very much! I just didnt know this case with supplemental. that explains everything . Thank you elmar Zander!!